# question marks in project explorer and version errors in pom.xml using Spring STS for Jhpister generated application

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jhipster, spring-tool-suite

I have generated **spring-boot** and **angularjs** based application using jhipster and imported as existing Maven Project in Spring STS.

The application is running fine but I did not understand what are those question marks (?) in the project explorer are? and also red marks in pom.xml for versions indicate?.

But still the application is running fine. I am not sure whether these issues cause problems in future and how can I get rid of them?

[image: springBooot]

Answer (score 0):

The question marks are coming from the version control integration and indicate that those files are not yet committed to version control.

The squiggle lines in the pom should reveal more information if you hover over them.